# Is it possible to move project collection between two organizations?

Tags: azure-devops

We are currently having a project collection with backlogs, sprints, etc. in an Azure DevOps account. There is another organization with completely different credentials to log in that we'd like to transfer this project collection to the other organization. I could not find any features or approaches to complete this transfer. Is there a way to be able to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not manually. Microsoft support *may* be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Mann please add your comment as an answer so I vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to migrate a project between organisations. This may become possible in the future, but [the feature suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html) is 8 years old and hasn't seen progress, *yet*.

However, depending on your requirements, you might be able to create your own tools/scripts to "re-create" your project in the new organisation using [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).